# Bypassing paths: Virtual drives gives LaTeX compilation error

Tags: compiling

When I try to solve this: [Failed to load pdf with includegraphics in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422250/126078) problem, I try to avoid the path name by making a virtual drive of my folder (there are many tools for this in diferent OS), so than a path

*/drive/documents/Latex-sources/document1/tex/*

become (e.g. in Windows)

*L:/tex/*

The result I get is that the compilator can't reach the location (with LaTeX, XeLaTeX, pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, and I don't try but I asume TeX fails too).

My questions are:

1. How can I bypass the path for compiling? (make virtualizing function would be great but maybe not the best solution)
2. Can I use a database with the code to compile LaTeX?
3. Is another way to compile without taking care of the path?

Comment: Can you simply run the compiler from the command line that has your document folder as a working directory? E. g. in Linux, it would be `cd /drive/documents/Latex-sources/document1/tex/` and then `pdflatex doc.tex`?

Comment: Sorry, I try the cd thing and it works the same, I can see how it copies the whole path in the log file.

Comment: The `.log` shows full paths but that's not normally how files are specified in a TeX source: most often one sets up such that not paths at all are required. I'm not clear how this question relates to the older one: if you've made a virtual drive, can't you just set `TEXINPUTS=L:/tex//:` or similar to make it appear 'here'?

Comment: @JosephWright, of course I dont use the full path to access to some source, I put all in a folder but, when compiling the paths are constructed for the compiler and, in some compilation routines (like in the problem I mention) the path have an important role that can make the compilation crash. The problem with my virtual drives I get is that compilers don't understand it and is just like asking to access for a file in an unexisting fisical hard drive.